# Regex: Does not contain sub string

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to test for strings that do not contain a particular sub string

Examples strings are:

```
event2
event23,event1,event67=12
event1,event30
event23
event2
event2,event23
```

I want to match strings that do not contain `event2`.

Therefore the following strings should match:
`event23,event1,event67=12`
`event1,event30`
`event23`

So far I can match strings the do contain `event2` with the following expression:
`/^.*(\bevent2\b)/gm`

But I don't know how to combine this with a negative lookahead.

This doesn't seem to work:
`/^.*(?!.*(\bevent2\b))/gm`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

[`^(?!.*event2\b).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/nhYnPP/2/)